# Converting a string to an integer on Android

Tags: java, android, string, integer, android-edittext

How do I convert a string into an integer?

I have a textbox I have the user enter a number into:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry1);
String hello = et.getText().toString();
```

And the value is assigned to the string `hello`.

I want to convert it to a integer so I can get the number they typed; it will be used later on in code.

Is there a way to get the `EditText` to a integer? That would skip the middle man. If not, string to integer will be just fine.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 468, accepted):

See the Integer class and the static `parseInt()` method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html

```
Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

You will need to catch `NumberFormatException` though in case of problems whilst parsing, so:

```
int myNum = 0;

try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
}
```

Comment: What about using manuel's way below? Is it more secure to use parseInt over valueOf?

Answer (score 51):

```
int in = Integer.valueOf(et.getText().toString());
//or
int in2 = new Integer(et.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 28):

**Use regular expression:**

```
String s="your1string2contain3with4number";
int i=Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

output:
i=1234;

**If you need first number combination then you should try below code:**

```
String s="abc123xyz456";
int i=NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(s).intValue();
```

output:
i=123;

Answer (score 13):

**Use regular expression:**

```
int i=Integer.parseInt("hello123".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
int j=Integer.parseInt("123hello".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
int k=Integer.parseInt("1h2el3lo".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
```

**output:**

```
i=123;
j=123;
k=123;
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Use regular expression is best  way to doing this as already mentioned by ashish sahu

```
public int getInt(String s){
return Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code it's really working.

```
int number = 0;
try {
    number = Integer.parseInt(YourEditTextName.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("parse value is not valid : " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Best way to convert your string into int is :

```
 EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry1);
 String hello = et.getText().toString();
 int converted=Integer.parseInt(hello);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should covert String to float. It is working.

```
float result = 0;
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString()) {
  return;
}

result = Float.parseFloat(et.getText().toString());

tv.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to parse a string to an integer:

**int value=Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());**

*(1)* *input:* 12 then it will work.. because textview has taken this 12 number as "12" string.

*(2) input:* "abdul" then it will throw an exception that is NumberFormatException.
     So to solve this we need to use try catch as I have mention below:

```
  int tax_amount=20;
  EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     try
       {

        int value=Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
        value=value+tax_amount;
        edit.setText(String.valueOf(value));// to convert integer to string 

       }catch(NumberFormatException ee){
       Log.e(ee.toString());
       }
```

You may also want to refer to the following link for more information:
**http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html**

Answer (score 5):

There are five ways to convert
The First Way :

```
String str = " 123" ;
int i = Integer.parse(str); 
output : 123
```

The second way :

```
String str = "hello123world";
int i = Integer.parse(str.replaceAll("[\\D]" , "" ) );
output : 123
```

The Third Way :

```
String str"123";
int i = new Integer(str);
output "123
```

The Fourth Way :

```
String str"123";
int i = Integer.valueOf(Str);
output "123
```

The Fifth Way :

```
String str"123";
int i = Integer.decode(str);
output "123
```

There could be other ways
But that's what I remember now

Comment: Mark your code parts as code; that will make the answer more readable!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it one line:

```
int hello = Integer.parseInt(((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).getText().toString().replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

Reading from order of execution

1. grab the view using `findViewById(R.id.button1)`
2. use `((Button)______)` to cast the `View` as a `Button`
3. Call  `.GetText()`  to get the text entry from Button
4. Call `.toString()` to convert the Character Varying to a String
5. Call `.ReplaceAll()` with `"[\\D]"` to replace all Non Digit Characters with "" (nothing)
6. Call `Integer.parseInt()` grab  and return an integer out of the Digit-only string.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for one line (just my preference).

Comment: Aye, I wouldnt do it that way either, it was more a reference to the OP's "skip the middle man" comment.

Answer (score 3):

The much simpler method is to use the `decode` method of `Integer` so for example:

```
int helloInt = Integer.decode(hello);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Kotlin

There are available Extension methods to parse them into other primitive types.

- [`"10".toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-int.html)
- [`"10".toLong()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-long.html)
- [`"true".toBoolean()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-boolean.html)
- [`"10.0".toFloat()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-float.html)
- [`"10.0".toDouble()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-double.html)
- [`"10".toByte()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-byte.html)
- [`"10".toShort()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-short.html)

#### Java

```
String num = "10";
Integer.parseInt(num );
```

Answer (score 2):

I have simply change this

```
int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

into

```
int j = 1;
```

AND IT SOLVE MY PROBLEM