# How to convert string to long

Tags: java, android, string, converters, long-integer

how do you convert a string into a long.

for int you

```
int i = 3423;
String str;
str = str.valueOf(i);
```

so how do you go the other way but with long.

```
long lg;
String Str = "1333073704000"
lg = lg.valueOf(Str);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709269/108574

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This is a common way to do it:

```
long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

There is also this method: `Long.valueOf(str);` Difference is that `parseLong` returns a primitive `long` while `valueOf` returns a `new Long()` object.

Comment: Thank you.
i got stuck on lg.getLong as per [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#getLong(java.lang.String))

Comment: `getLong` returns a long from a system property. That's why it does not work as you expected.

Comment: It is easy to make the mistake of assuming the input string is in the form you expect ; "90.77" will throw ParseException with this. So dont ignore the ParseException, but handle it for your use case

Answer (score 9):

The method for converting a string to a long is [Long.parseLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29).  Modifying your example:

```
String s = "1333073704000";
long l = Long.parseLong(s);
// Now l = 1333073704000
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = "1";

try {
   long l = Long.parseLong(s);       
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

IF your input is String then I recommend you to store the String into a double and then convert the double to the long.

```
String str = "123.45";
Double  a = Double.parseDouble(str);

long b = Math.round(a);
```

Comment: Could you also add why you think this is better than simply calling `parseLong()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try following,

```
long lg;
String Str = "1333073704000"
lg = Long.parseLong(Str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;
```

This will handle `null`

```
NumberUtils.createLong(String)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parseLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)), e.g.:

```
long lg = lg.parseLong("123456789123456789");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

However, always check that str contains digits to prevent throwing exceptions.
For instance:

```
String str="ABCDE";
long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

would throw an exception but this

```
String str="1234567";
long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

won't.