# How to convert String taken from a texfield view to an int

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert string to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Please, I am developing an android application (Java, XML). How can I get a text from a textfield and convert it to an integer?

Comment: @M Najib: Add appropriate tags. Use 'Android' as the tag instead of 'string' & 'int'.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-android

Answer (score 1):

number = Integer.parseInt(yourStringHere);