# Convert strings to integer in android

Tags: android

How do I convert string to integer?

I have tries many ways and it seems to be showing some error.
example  "100" which is in integer format"

```
 email.get(0);
```

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(YourString)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an integer on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android)

Comment: What about Integer.parse("string");

Comment: Integer.parseInt("string")

Comment: You should search before posting questions.. this is duplicate

Comment: Was in a hurry..sorry:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse like following code:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(email.get(0));
```