# How to sort arrayList according to Integer size in android?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I am sorting my array list int items by using "compareTo(String string);" this method comparing only string but not int values.How I can sort my array list based on integer value.

Here is my code :

```
 Collections.sort(mAllSpeedsArray, new AllSpeedsComparator());

public class AllSpeedsComparator implements Comparator<AllSpeeds> {

@Override
public int compare(AllSpeeds lhs, AllSpeeds rhs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        return lhs.getSpeed().compareTo(rhs.getSpeed());        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is early. Not Collections.swap(), Collections.sort(allSpeedsArray);

Comment: Maybe an other possibility is to convert string to integers and then comparing them (> etc ...). To convert: `int stringVal = Integer.parseInt("myString");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an integer on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android)

Comment: Mix my comment with @smagnan and looks like a quick and easy to me :P

Comment: yes @smagnam I tried this but I am not getting exact sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
@Override
public int compare(AllSpeeds lhs, AllSpeeds rhs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    int a = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getSpeed());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getSpeed());
    return a < b ? 1 : (a == b ? 0 : -1);
}
```

Comment: that return method giving  "Cannot cast from String to Integer" error.Because my getSpeed() is String type.

Comment: Update one giving "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

Answer (score 3):

Either make your AllSpeeds data structure return an `int` (or `double`, or something else numeric) from `getSpeed()`, or use `Integer.parse(string)` on the two strings and then compare the integers.

Comment: like this   int firstSpeed = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getSpeed());
  int secondSpeed = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getSpeed());

Comment: And I am comparing this 2 Inegers like this if (firstSpeed < secondSpeed) {
   return firstSpeed;
  } else  {
   return secondSpeed;
  }

Comment: But it always executing else block only.

Comment: you can return `firstSpeed - secondSpeed`.