# Android covert string to integer numberformatexception

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

My goal is to take the digits out of a string and convert it to an int.
For example:
12.7 (string) would become 127 (int)
156-06 (string) would become 15606 (int)

This is the code I used:

```
private static int convertToDigits(String input){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if(c > 47 && c < 58){
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    String result = sb.toString().trim();
    Log.d("Result", result);
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
}
```

When I log the result I am getting 127 as the string value I want, but when I convert that to an int, I get a `NumberFormatException`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.dcasillasappdev.mytrackfieldteam.utility.Utility.convertToDigits(Utility.java:333)
```

Am I missing something here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android

Comment: Can you give an example of an input not handled correctly?

Comment: are you sure that you are logging result ? Accordingly to the exception, result is empty

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` An empty string is **not** 0!

Comment: Ok so I put inputted 12.7 and here's the log: 
10-02 14:07:38.100  10383-10383/com.dcasillasappdev.myapp D/Result﹕ 127

Comment: I think I got it everyone.  This method is running in a loop and could be failing after the first input and I don't realize it.  I'm going to look into it.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, the case of empty input.
Your method works fine for non-empty strings,
you just need to add special treatment for empty input,
for example:

```
if (input.isEmpty()) {
    return 0;  // or whatever way you want to handle this case ...
}
```

Btw, here's a simpler way to strip all non-digit characters and convert to an `int`:

```
return Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

But if you really want to stick to your original approach iterating over the characters and using a string builder, then here's a better way to write that:

```
private static int convertToDigits(String input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
}
```

Comment: I also tried running your method and I'm still getting "Invalid int: "".  I'm confused why I'm getting an empty input when my log is showing a valid int.

Comment: i figured out what went wrong.  Janos your answer was helpful.