# How to convert string to integer in android?

Tags: java, android

i want to convert userid(string) to integer but app get to crashed why?
if i removes converted method then no crashed but i want integer value what i do?

```
  public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
  }
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       /**
        * Get stored session data userid from other class
        **/
        userid = "";
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());//<-- this 
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        userid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_userid);

        /*i want convert userid to int, when i try to 
          convert then app is carashed. pls help me what i am missing here*/

        Integer U_ID = Integer.valueOf(userid);
        if(U_ID >0){
            Toast.makeText(GcmMessageHandler.this, "new on id="+userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

if i removes convert function then app not crashed, but i want integer valued what i do?

Comment: use `Integer.parseInt(userid)` instead of `Integer.valueOf(userid);`. If `userid` is blank, it will not work

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: i did it but still app crashed

Comment: You should use the debugger to ensure that the value inside of `userid` can actually be converted into an `Integer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an integer on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android)

Comment: Post your crash logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
if(userid != null && !userid.trim().isEmpty()){
     int  U_ID = Integer.parseInt(userid)
}
```

Comment: please try the sasikumar code ! your problem has been solved.