# Get the int number from TextView decrease by one and set new text

Tags: java, android, int, type-conversion

I have a TextView with text number 50.
I need to get this value, decrease it by 1 (49 the result) and set the new value on my Textview.

My code so far:

```
TextView mynumber;

mynumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mynumber);
String coinstext = mynumber.getText().toString();
                mynumber.setText(coinstext -1);
```

Completely failure... any idea please?

Comment: What you get from textview is a string, you need to convert it to int or numeric types before doing any arithmetic operations. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709253/1155650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(mynumber.getText().toString());
x = x - 1;
mynumber.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```