# How to parse BluetoothGattCharacteristic value in java

Tags: java, android, c, arduino, bluetooth-gatt

I'm currently a bit lost in trying to figuring out how to transfer data from my ESP32 microcontroller to android phone. I have managed to send and read characteristics value, but don't know how to parse it.. For now, I'm sending simple integer value = `15`.

I found out that the data is sent using a byte array, therefore I converted it to hex-string and the result doesn't make sense `31-35-2E-30-30`. Checked the *nRF connect* app it also displays the same hex-string result but in addition it has parsed the value to `15.00`.

**Here is the Arduino code:**

```
...
char txString[8];
int someNumber = 15;
dtostrf(someNumber, 1, 2, txString);

_pCharacteristicNotify -> setValue(txString);
_pCharacteristicNotify -> notify();
...
```

**Android Studio**

```
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    _handler.handleMessage(Message.obtain(null, ..., characteristic));
}

private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // ------- The problem is here ----------------
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        characteristic = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) msg.obj;
        String value = Utils.parseBLECharacteristicValue(characteristic);
        // the value is "31-35-2E-30-30"
        // HOW TO GET THE NUMBER 15 ??
    }
};
```

The parse method that I'm using is from here [Example 1](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic&method=getValue)

Could someone please explain me how to parse the given value?

And how the logic would change if the provided value is string `"abcd123"` not an integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`31-35-2E-30-30` is the ASCII representation of the string `15.00`.

According to the [dtostrf() documentation](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html):

> Conversion is done in the format "[-]d.ddd".

which explains the string 15.00 with two decimal values due to your third argument to the call being `2`.

Try to use the [String constructor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringConstructor) of Arduino for your integer-to-string conversion. Afterwards, you can use the Integer class in Android to convert the string back to an integer as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check it out.