# Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find some of the total prices from my collects but it seems there is a data mismatch somewhere I can't solve so if anyone can assist me to do so I will be thankful

```
val id = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tempCart").child(id)

dref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){

            for (cartSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                val cart = cartSnapshot.getValue(CartData::class.java)
                cartList.add(cart!!)

                toto = cartSnapshot.child("totalPrice").getValue(Int::class.java)!!

                toto += toto
            }
            orderCost.text = toto.toString()

            cartRecycler.adapter = cartAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

I have tried several times to fix it by reading the guides online they are changing the data from firebase to integer, but when I do so it tells me I cant cast `java.lang.string` to `int`

[image: this is how my collections look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your total price may be a numeric value, but you stored it as a string in your database. So you will have to read that string value from the database, and then convert it to a number:

```
val str = cartSnapshot.child("totalPrice").getValue(String::class.java)!!
val value = str.toInt();
toto += value
```

I strongly recommend storing the `totalPrice` as a number in the database though, as its best to fix this type of type conversion problem at the source.

Comment: how can i store the data as number

Comment: [How to parse a string to a number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android)